# how to handle transaction management in multi datasource using atomikos?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jdbctemplate, atomikos

I am having one application with multiple datasource and i am facing one issue where i am calling both datasource in one transaction and i am getting result from first datasource but when i am trying to get result from second datasource i am getting exception so at that time i want to rollback both the datasource result. so how we can do that using atomikos? or we have any other way to do it? I know one way ChainedTransactionManager but it is deprecated so we can't use it.

Let me know if you have anyways to handle above situation.

My expected result is to find a way to rollback both the datasource result when we get exception in any datasource result.

Answer (score 0):

try PlatformTransactionManager here is the doc https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/transaction/PlatformTransactionManager.html .This bloger has the same problem with you https://medium.com/@inzuael/how-to-use-multiple-datasources-with-springboot-exposed-jpa-6bd705bfe994

Comment: Hi @lamic Zo, Above post is related to JPA but i need to implement it with JDBC Template. Do you have any other reference for that?

Comment: I wonder if this would help https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch11s06.html;this is about using transaction management in Spring jdbcTemplate; 11.6.2 Using the PlatformTransactionManager is also in the documentation

Comment: Hi @Lamic Zo,above page is not found.

Comment: try this one https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch11s06.html